# on page edit divi builder not displaying content

Tags: wordpress, builder

Whenever I am trying to edit page through the Divi builder but that Divi builder not showing me my old saved content.
Note: In my website, WordPress auto update is on so my WordPress is up to date with 4.9.7 and that version is released on
5 July 2018.

[image: Below is the screenshot I have attached that display current interface display on the page edit time.]

Answer (score 0):

if the old content wasn't built using divi builder then you will either see it as a text or it wont be displayed.

Comment: My old content built with divi builder and after edit time I am facing that issue.

Comment: I have the same problem with divi builder. Did you find a solution for it?